Inconsistent result of ctypes - GetAsyncKeyState function
import ctypes

def mouse_released() -> bool:
    mouse_state = ctypes.windll.user32.GetAsyncKeyState(0x01)
    if mouse_state:
        while ctypes.windll.user32.GetAsyncKeyState(0x01):
            continue  # is pressing
        else:
            print('released')
            return mouse_state != 0 # released
    return False

while True:
    mouse_released()


This program tells if the left mouse button was released.
Problem: in general it works correctly. But sometimes at the very beginning it prints "released", even though nothing was pressed even a few seconds before.
I tried to change the GetAsyncKeyState with GetKeyState. It seemed to solve the mentioned problem, but this way, the function indicates the button being pressed only every second time, which is a complete mistery to me.

Doesn't it eat a whole CPU? You should add a time.sleep(0.01) in your while loop. Also, not the cause of your problem, but [SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer). Your result logic might need some improvement (on MSB and LSB, not just comparing to 0).

the LSB of GetKeyState is a toggle so the value will be non-zero every two presses.  If you are testing pressed or not, only check the MSB (mouse_state & 0x8000).  You should only check MSB on GetAsyncKeyState as well.  the LSB only indicates "pressed since last call to GetAsyncKeyState" and is unreliable since another app can be calling it as well.

Considering all the comments, this is the working method I came up with:
from win32api import GetKeyState

def mouse_released():
    pressed = GetKeyState(0x01) < 0
    if pressed:
        while GetKeyState(0x01) < 0:
            continue # Wait until the button is released
    return pressed

